# Biblatex: how to typeset Working Paper as an Article

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm using the authoryear style for biblatex. I would like to typeset a Working Paper that has published in working paper series as an article. In the sense that I would like the title to be put between quotes, and the title of the Working Paper series to be considered like a journal title. Currently, the working paper is treated more or less as a book.

Is there a way to do this without changing the entries in the bib file itself?

MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[
 backend=biber,  style=authoryear,  
 url=false,eprint=false,doi=false,dashed=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{acf_identification_2015,
    author               = {Ackerberg, Daniel and Caves, Kevin and Frazer, Garth},
    doi                  = {10.3982/ECTA13408},
    issn                 = {1468-0262},
    journal              = {Econometrica},
    keywords             = {Production functions , productivity , total factor productivity , productivity growth},
    number               = {6},
    pages                = {2411--2451},
    publisher            = {Blackwell Publishing Ltd},
    title                = {Identification Properties of Recent Production Function Estimators},
    url                  = {http://dx.doi.org/10.3982/ECTA13408},
    volume               = {83},
    year                 = {2015},
}
@Report{ackerberg_structural_2006,
    author      = {Ackerberg, Daniel and Caves, Kevin and Frazer, Garth},
    title       = {Structural Identification of Production Functions},
    type        = {MPRA Paper},
    institution = {University Library of Munich, Germany},
    year        = {2006},
    number      = {38349},
    url         = {http://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/38349/},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Dummytext~\autocite{acf_identification_2015,ackerberg_structural_2006}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Are the changes you explicitly mention (`title` and 'series' -> `type`?) the only ones you need to make `@report`s look like `@article`s or is there more to it?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a very crude workaround, by using the formatting commands:

```
% Titles of working papers should be in quotes
\DeclareFieldFormat[techreport,report,unpublished]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
% The type or series should be in italics
\DeclareFieldFormat[techreport,report,unpublished]{type}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

Comment: Not sure why you would call this 'crude'. It is exactly the right way to make sure that titles are in quotation marks and the `type` in `\emph`.

Comment: Why do `\DeclareFieldFormat`-solutions only pertain to the title as it occurs *in the bibliography* **but not** to the titles if they are invoked in the running text by `\cite{...}`? (try the above MWE with `style=authortitle`)